# AEM 6.4 upgrade post upgrade issue with packages

Tags: aem, upgrade

Post upgrade from AEM 6.2 with SP1 to AEM 6.4 few of the packages are not installed. The older version is on installed state.

For the new package is showing the message as "A different version seems to be installed:" see the below screen shot.

Because of this i could see few of the scripts are not updated with latest API. 
For example 
AEM 6.4 upgraded instance : `/libs/cq/ui/components/widget/html.jsp -> API reference com.day.cq.widget.HtmlLibraryManager`

AEM 6.4 Vanila instance : `/libs/cq/ui/components/widget/html.jsp -> API reference com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.HtmlLibraryManager`

This issue is currently resolved by overlaying the file and updated with the new API com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.HtmlLibraryManager

[image]

This package is not able to install manually. When i am trying to install getting the error as javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: OakConstraint0074: Attempt to add, modify or remove the system maintained property 'rep:externalId'.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of upgrade is not done properly. During the upgrade few packages is not upgraded from older version to new version due to javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException. This is because of custom code has updated 'rep:externalId' to the users and system user in the AEM 6.2 instance. During the upgrade this properly in the System user creates javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException. So i have deleted this property from system user before upgrade. This works for the above problem.

**Note :** Since Oak 1.5.8 the system-maintained property rep:externalId is protected and can not be altered using regular JCR and Jackrabbit API, irrespective of the permission setup of the editing session.